# aggregating hourly data to day with the percent

Tags: sql, oracle

Based on the following data, how do we convert to a percent of CPU idle and Used, aggregated to a day?

For example, I'm looking for aggregate status to show the CPU utilization on this Day 18-JUN-15 is 97% idle and 10% busy, Day 19-JUN-15% is 80% idle and 20% busy... and so on

```
18-JUN-15 05.00.15.571 AM                                                        98.75        .69        .55         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 06.00.18.183 AM                                                        98.37          1        .63         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 07.00.03.804 AM                                                        97.67       1.56        .76         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 08.00.07.987 AM                                                        97.78       1.46        .75         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 09.00.00.707 AM                                                         97.8       1.44        .75         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 10.00.03.628 AM                                                        97.06       2.09        .84         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 11.00.06.660 AM                                                        97.92       1.36        .71         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 12.00.09.538 PM                                                        97.93       1.34        .72           0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 01.00.12.455 PM                                                        97.95       1.31        .73         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 02.00.15.177 PM                                                        97.92       1.34        .73         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 03.00.17.829 PM                                                        98.11       1.18         .7         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 04.00.20.657 PM                                                        98.58        .82        .59         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 05.00.23.284 PM                                                        94.32       4.29       1.38         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 06.00.26.366 PM                                                        91.97       6.38       1.64         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 07.00.30.108 PM                                                        98.51        .88         .6         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 08.00.34.282 PM                                                        98.78        .67        .55         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 09.00.02.411 PM                                                        96.39       3.01        .59         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 10.00.05.019 PM                                                        97.91       1.53        .55         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
18-JUN-15 11.00.07.827 PM                                                        98.64        .79        .56         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 12.00.10.329 AM                                                        98.07       1.27        .65           0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 01.00.12.954 AM                                                        98.65        .79        .56           0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 02.00.15.499 AM                                                         96.9       2.23        .86         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 03.00.18.041 AM                                                        98.75        .68        .57         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 04.00.01.618 AM                                                        98.72        .71        .56         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 05.00.05.221 AM                                                        98.73         .7        .56         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 06.00.08.719 AM                                                        98.48        .91        .61         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 07.00.12.035 AM                                                        97.39       1.79        .81         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 08.00.14.827 AM                                                        97.42       1.76        .81         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 09.00.17.804 AM                                                         97.4       1.76        .83         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 10.00.20.560 AM                                                        97.98       1.29        .72         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 11.00.02.756 AM                                                        98.07       1.23         .7         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 12.00.07.015 PM                                                         98.1        1.2         .7         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 01.00.10.953 PM                                                        98.03       1.24        .72         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 02.00.15.406 PM                                                        97.84       1.42        .73         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 03.00.19.628 PM                                                        98.03       1.25        .72         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 04.00.24.111 PM                                                        98.56        .83         .6         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 05.00.28.252 PM                                                        94.54       4.13       1.33           0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 06.00.32.564 PM                                                        89.79        8.2          2         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 07.00.01.336 PM                                                         98.6         .8        .59         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 08.00.05.105 PM                                                        98.76        .68        .55         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 09.00.07.931 PM                                                        96.08       3.29        .62         .01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
19-JUN-15 10.00.10.508 PM                                                        97.87       1.57        .56         .01
```

Comment: just throwing a number, it could be 97%

Comment: So average the idle time?

Comment: Don't just just want the average for the column(s), grouped by the day (truncated interval time)? Or maybe adjusted by an hour, depending on what the time represents and what you want to see?

Comment: Yes, that could be possible. Can you share the sql how it should be? I may need to modify it to separate business hours vs non-business hours later.

Comment: @user1595858 - something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8095054/266304)?

Comment: @AlexPoole thats seems to be exactly wht I was asking. In addition to it can we filter the data to see only between 9am-5pm of a day only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic aggregate is as in the linked question:

```
select trunc(begin_interval_time) as day,
  avg(idle_time) as avg_idle,
  100 - avg(idle_time) as avg_busy
from your_table
group by trunc(begin_interval_time)
order by trunc(begin_interval_time);

DAY          AVG_IDLE   AVG_BUSY
---------- ---------- ----------
2015-06-18 97.4926316 2.50736842
2015-06-19 97.5113043 2.48869565
```

This takes 'busy' as the opposite of idle; you could instead add up the three other values:

```
avg(user_time + sys_time + iowait_time) as avg_busy
```

but the two won't usually add up to exactly 100 as the precision of the values isn't high enough.

Assuming "between 9am-5pm" means from 09:00:00.000 to 16:59:59.999, you can just filter on the hour being between 9 and 16:

```
select trunc(begin_interval_time) as day,
  avg(idle_time) as avg_idle,
  100 - avg(idle_time) as avg_busy
from your_table
where extract(hour from begin_interval_time) between 9 and 16
group by trunc(begin_interval_time)
order by trunc(begin_interval_time);

DAY          AVG_IDLE   AVG_BUSY
---------- ---------- ----------
2015-06-18   97.90875    2.09125
2015-06-19   98.00125    1.99875
```

If you want to see both work and non-work hours you can sue case expressions:

```
select trunc(begin_interval_time) as day,
  avg(case when extract(hour from begin_interval_time)
    between 9 and 16 then idle_time end) as avg_idle_work,
  100 - avg(case when extract(hour from begin_interval_time)
    between 9 and 16 then idle_time end) as avg_busy_work,
  avg(case when extract(hour from begin_interval_time)
    not between 9 and 16 then idle_time end) as avg_idle_non_work,
  100 - avg(case when extract(hour from begin_interval_time)
    not between 9 and 16 then idle_time end) as avg_busy_non_work
from your_table
group by trunc(begin_interval_time)
order by trunc(begin_interval_time);

DAY        AVG_IDLE_WORK AVG_BUSY_WORK AVG_IDLE_NON_WORK AVG_BUSY_NON_WORK
---------- ------------- ------------- ----------------- -----------------
2015-06-18      97.90875       2.09125             97.19              2.81
2015-06-19      98.00125       1.99875             97.25              2.75
```

If that isn't quite what you mean for the work-hours you can modify the `extract()` calls to split it wherever you need.

---

You *may* want to adjust the times slightly during the calculation, depending on what that timestamp represents; e.g. truncate to hour level, and then maybe subtract an hour. It depends if say '19-JUN-15 12.00.10.329 AM' is supposed to count against the 18th or 19th. If you are only look at work hours it probably doesn't matter, and you might not care anyway...

Comment: absolutely is what I need.

Comment: I found one caveat with it, it also consider weekends as work days. That something needs to be filtered.

Comment: If you're using the second query then it's easy enough to add a filter on day-of-week (keeping NLS settings in mind; the D element varies depending on where you are, and using DY or DAY needs to specify the language). If you're using the third one you can incorporate that into the case expressions, which gets a bit messy. But, that only handles weekends, not holidays - it's common to have a look-up table to identify those instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will aggregate the idle time per day between 9am and 5pm only. 16 is the same as less than 5pm in 24hr time format.

```
Select TRUNC(BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME) as BEGIN_DATE,
AVG(IDLE_TIME) as AVG_IDLE_TIME
From tbl 
Where TO_CHAR(BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME, 'HH24') Between 9 and 16
Group by TRUNC(BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME)
```